# Root Element Missing - Creating Xmldocument using XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm having the following code which is spitting 'Root Element Missing' during `doc.Load()`.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
xmlWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
stream.Position = 0;
doc.Load(stream);
xmlWriter.Close();
```

I'm not able to figure out the issue. Any insights?

Comment: (Something unrelated: While it's not strictly necessary, you could wrap the code in `using` blocks for both your `MemoryStream` and `XmlTextWriter` objects -- they are both `IDisposable`.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't flushed the `xmlWriter`, so it may well not have written anything out yet. Also, you're never completing the root element, so even if it *has* written out

```
<Root>
```

it won't have written the closing tag. You're trying to load it as a *complete document*.

I'm not sure at what point an XmlWriter *actually* writes out the starting part of an element anyway - don't forget it may have attributes to write too. The most it could write out with the code you've got is `<Root`.

Here's a complete program which works:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            xmlWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
            xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlWriter.Flush();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            stream.Position = 0;
            doc.Load(stream);
            doc.Save(Console.Out);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that I'm not calling `WriteEndDocument` - that only seems to be necessary if you still have open elements or attributes.)

Comment: Point of order: is .Close() not usually more correct than .Flush()?

Comment: @annalata: I assume that would close the stream, which we don't want to do here. Usually I would just dispose the writer though.

Answer (score 0):

What @Skeet said, plus, you don't seem to close your element:

```
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: I covered that in my second sentence :)

Comment: Indeed you did, but in *stealth mode* -- that's the only reason I could comprehend as to why I would have missed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I see you starting the document, but I don't see you [ending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writeenddocument.aspx) it or [closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.close.aspx) it... (at least not before you use it)